# PHP send multiple emails without stopping the execution

Tags: php, email, cakephp-2.0

As i am trying to send more than 400 emails at once, as an invites for one application. 
I dont want to stop the user who is inviting the 400 people till the last email goes out.
I dont want to use cron job for the same, as 1st store the emails to the DB & then set a cron job which will take care of email sending in background.

As i want to run this process in background. I was trying Gearman for the same. 
Anybody has any other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Are all messages contents unique? Otherwise you must send only one single message to all receipients.

Comment: To me "processing in background" and "not stop the user until the last message is sent" sounds like a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run an external application as a background process.

If your server is are running linux you can try this:

```
exec("sudo /path/to/external/application args > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

The external process could be a php script too using [PHP cli](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php).